# add precipitation trend line above heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heat map like the one below:

Example of a heat map I am trying to create. The black trendline on the top is the precipitation trendline

[image: Example of a heat map I am trying to create. The black trendline on the top is the precipitation trendline]

I have created the following heat map in R using the rlakeanalyzer package. I'm new to R and I can't find a helpful solution to adding a precipitation trendline above my heat map like the example has.

The heat map I have created "Talus North Heat Map"

[image: The heat map I have created "Talus North Heat Map"]

I have used the following code to create my heat map

```
TalusNorthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusNorthdf, zlim = c(0, 20),
                              plot.title = title(
                                main = "Talus North Water Temp (C)",
                                xlab = "Date",
                                ylab = "Depth (m)"))
```

A snap shot of my TalusNorthdf str.

```
'data.frame':   8579 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ datetime..GMT.: POSIXct, format: "2023-07-07 21:20:35" "2023-07-07 21:35:35" "2023-07-07 21:50:35" "2023-07-07 22:05:35" ...
 $ wtr_0.0       : num  10.7 10.8 10.4 10.4 10.3 ...
 $ wtr_1.0       : num  11.1 11 10.9 10.9 10.8 ...
 $ wtr_3.0       : num  8.68 8.78 8.78 8.78 8.38 ...
 $ wtr_4.0       : num  7.88 7.98 8.08 7.98 7.78 ...
 $ wtr_5.0       : num  7.28 7.38 7.38 7.28 7.18 ...
```

Comment: `rLakeAnalyzer` uses base graphics, so methods might include: `par(mfrow=...)` or `layout(..)`, or perhaps some bespoke package I don't know of. It's hard to produce reproducible questions on high-ish size heatmap data, perhaps it'd be easier to use sample data included in the package (see `?wtr.heat.map` to get to it), and then I suggest you explain what data is supporting that marginal barplot.

Comment: @r2evans I know layout is used - I'm not sure what that means exactly. I've been using R for 8 days now, and it's the first time I have used any type of programming language. How do I find out what data supports the marginal barplot, and what is the marginal barplot......sorry complete beginner here

Comment: Wow, eight days in and you're attempting multi-plot combinations. [`?layout`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html) has some examples to work through. From there, you still need to figure out (or just _explain_) what exactly is going into that marginal barplot. (Oh, for that ... it's a _barplot_ in the _margins_ of the main plot. Marginal barplot. Nothing cosmic there :-)

Comment: I'm not trying to stiff-arm you ... I honestly don't know how you are determining how the additional stuff over the plot. Is it just `hist` with an uber-narrow bin width?

Comment: The additional stuff over the plot is a precip trendline I created using ggplot/ geom_line. The data has the same start and end date as the heat map data so the x axis's are the same, but I need to get the geom_line on top of the heat map.

Comment: I don't know of any package out there that faithfully joins base graphics and ggplot graphics while perfectly preserving the axes, perhaps I'm wrong. This is made more difficult b/c `filled.contour` (used to plot) is using space in the "figure" to put the legend, making it nearly impossible to know programmatically where the actual plot region stops, making the use of `layout` or `par(mfrow=)` problematic at best. If you want the marginal trendline, I suggest switching from `rLakeAnalyzer` to `ggplot2::geom_contour_filled` or such, then use `ggExtra::ggMarginal` or similar.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase a little: `filled.contour` is _already_ using `layout`, so your best bet to get it laid out correctly will be to start with that `graphics::filled.contour` and change how the `layout` is setup.